# Create HTML Reports with JBoss?

Tags: java, html, jboss, report

Are there any libraries (built-in or third party) for writing .html reports with JBoss apps quickly and easily?

I have a list of entities in a database that I want to display in different tables.  There will need to be things like links within the report to go from some parts of the report to other parts, sorting/paging, and some nice CSS to make the report pretty would be nice.

I have an existing application that produces the .html and .css programmatically, but due to the huge size of the data (124Mb in some cases), the writing of the .html takes way too long (40+ minutes) and often freezes up the browser.  So I am looking for an alternative.

I guess one solution is to write JSF forms that fill rich tables with bean data, but I am not sure if this is the best approach.

Replies highly valued!  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JasperReports](http://www.jasperforge.net/projects/jasperreports) is open source, flexible, and perfect for my needs (I am reporting using xml data, and a simple transformation will be perfect to JSXML format to produce reports in this way).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [JQuery](http://jquery.com/)?  It offers large number of plug-ins to achive pagination, tables, sorting etc. and it sound like it might be a good fit for your case.

Comment: Thanks.  I am trying to avoid using Javascript for security reasons (and lack of skills!), sorry I did not specify earlier.  I heard Jasper is another option for Java.

Comment: Yes, Japser would be a good choice in that case.  If you are going to generate a lot of HTMLs in production, I suggest you tune perm gen memory accordingly.  You can find more information on Jasper's web site.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep the perm gen memory tuning idea in mind. Cheers